Remove MTEXT and DIMENSION in dxf
I need to detect closed polygon in DXF file in python, i have used ezdxf and open-cv.
docMsp = doc.modelspace()

        for e in doc.entities:
            if e.dxftype() == 'MTEXT' or e.dxftype() == 'DIMENSION':
                docMsp.delete_entity(e)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
        ctx = RenderContext(doc)
        out = MatplotlibBackend(ax)

        cfg = config.Configuration(
            background_policy=config.BackgroundPolicy.BLACK,
            color_policy=config.ColorPolicy.WHITE,
        )

        frontend = Frontend(ctx, out, config=cfg)       
        frontend.draw_layout(docMsp, finalize=True)
        fig.canvas.draw()

        graph_image = np.array(fig.canvas.get_renderer()._renderer)
        imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(graph_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        
        forms.append("Number of contours: " + str(len(contours)/2))

This peace of code work as espected when DXF file no contain MTEXT or DIMENSION, the lib ezdxf doesn't eliminate all dimensions in somes files when run in this part :
for e in doc.entities:
  if e.dxftype() == 'MTEXT' or e.dxftype() == 'DIMENSION':
    docMsp.delete_entity(e)

Is there another way to eliminate ALL text, dimension and keep only image polygon ?
Or maybe another way to detect closed Polygon ?
